# ConstraintLayout crash with StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have multiple strange crash reports via Firebase Crashlytics during last week from different devices. 
They are:

- 100% from Android 4 (4.2 - 4.4)
- Mostly (98%) from Samsung tablets

Stack traces are identical and doesn't include any reference to my code, so I dont know where crash happen and why. Searching for my exception gives nothing. So I hope somebody can help me investigating that crashes. As I understand, crash happen somewhere inside ConstraintLayout library (I use version 1.1.3).

Crash stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
   at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.<init>(HashMap.java:911)
   at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.<init>(HashMap.java:911)
   at java.util.HashMap.keySet(HashMap.java:696)
   at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:161)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ResolutionNode.didResolve(ResolutionNode.java:70)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ResolutionAnchor.resolve(ResolutionAnchor.java:140)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ResolutionNode.didResolve(ResolutionNode.java:71)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ResolutionAnchor.resolve(ResolutionAnchor.java:140)
----A lot of identical lines---- 
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ResolutionNode.didResolve(ResolutionNode.java:71)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ResolutionAnchor.resolve(ResolutionAnchor.java:85)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.solveGraph(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:586)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.optimize(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:643)
   at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:328)
   at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.solveLinearSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1860)
   at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1621)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1235)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:327)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
   at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2439)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1175)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5996)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Please help me to find out the reason of that crash or at least how to reproduce it.

**UPD:**

With help of my users I found out a place, where crash happens. It's an activity, where layout is not inflated from xml but generated in onCreate() by code (ConstraintLayout as root).

Comment: Check if you have put some "difficult" constraints (e.g. circular).

Comment: No, all constraints are simple. Maximum "difficulty" - is using Barriers. It's sad, that I dont know how to reproduce that crash. And layout that cause it. Difficult constraints can cause such exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out what was the reason.

I have an activity, where some number of Views were added dynamically depending on list with data passed to activity and type of every item. They were added to ConstraintLayout inside ScrollView. Crash happen when number of added views exceed ~30.

**Solution:**
I switched to RecyclerView to do more effective drawing and optimize memory usage and problem gone. Do not repeat my mistake and use RecyclerView to display large lists. Main mistake was that I could not imagine case, where that list will be really large but here we are.

That does not explain why crash happen only on Samsung devices and only on Android 4.2-4.4, but anyway it is better solution to use RecyclerView.